# Problem with estabilishing a connection on port 1521 with Oracle SQL Developer with Oracle DB on Azure cloud

Tags: oracle, azure, virtual-machine

My boyfriend was asked by his employer to create a VM on Azure and then to install the Oracle DB on it. This part is doable, there are many manuals on the internet.

The problem is that afterwards he needs to connect to it from a PC at home. On the first day the connection seems to be working. On the next day, it is rejected. He is using 1521 port secured with only his IP being allowed to connect. He is using Oracle SQL developer.

His admin made him block all other ports because almost immediately after installing this database there were already attacks from N. Korea. He is not doing anything secret, by the way, just normal company activities.

He has a fixed IP.

How can we establish a connection with Oracle installed on Azure cloud from Oracle SQL developer?

Even connecting to Oracle just with a port 1521 from another program, even terminal would be a great help because after two weeks of attempts we run out of ideas.

We tried Oracle 19, even Oracle 12 which is available in Azure store.

We tried GUI, we tried Bash (terminal), we tried mixed approaches.

Once Oracle is installed, and database created it works until the next day when it stops working.

Today we will try again re-doing all once again, I will keep adding error messages that appear.

One of the error messages is that SID is wrong. However, SID is established earlier and he does not change it. We went through manuals but the only way how SID is changed is when the admin, that is him, changes it.

Working hours of VM and Oracle are 24h per day, there is no hours when according to settings on Azure it would stay inactive. Installation is on fast SSD drives.

I searched the Internet and found many manuals that show how to do what I described on a step-by-step manner. It is hard for me to show all the links, because we keep doing it for 2 weeks now, 8 - 10 hours per day including weekends.

I know that we must be doing something wrong and this thing is probably very simple, just none of us can guess or find what we exactly do wrong.

If you need details. One of the attempts was based on this manual:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/oracle/oracle-database-quick-create

Connection worked in the first day and then it does not work, throws an error:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
(CONNECTION_ID=JlvBiUG7RNGM+9vvi3c3Sg==)
```

Here is the screenshot:

https://ibb.co/rsWBSRN

Our guess is that perhaps we make some mistake in this file: `etc/init/dbora`. Basically in no way we can access the Oracle nor its database.

Comment: I wouldn't bother blocking all ports except for one - it sounds like you are allowing by IP anyway, so I would start off by allowing all ports for your IP address. You can lock it down later if you need to.

Comment: Reinstalling everything when something does not work sounds pointless. Just keep the VM running, and make adjustments based on your research (or answers obtained here).

Comment: Your latest error sounds like you do have a low-level network connection, but that Oracle is not happy for some reason. Can you connect to the box via SSH and then run a console Oracle client in the shell? I seem to recall that the connection config in Oracle Server is a bit fussy.

Comment: I would say that two solid weeks of trying does sound rather excessive. The employer should have other colleagues who can help with this in a straightforward fashion, and I am wondering why they have left you floundering.

Comment: When running a console Oracle client in the shell we still cannot connect through ssh.

Comment: Can you create an SSH session to the box and then run a console Oracle client on the remote box (i.e. so it connects locally to the server on the VM)?

Comment: We are currently in Azure terminal and here ssh connection is not working. We cannot connect to VM or we might be doing it in the wrong way.

Comment: Now also ssh connection to VM stopped working. It was working until yesterday.

Comment: Right, it sounds like you are able to run commands on the box through a feature in the Azure web-based control panel ("Azure Terminal"). That is OK for now. So, I would suggest getting the console Oracle client working here first. That will allow you to ensure that the server is accepting connections (not just basic networking connections, but Oracle is willing to service them).

Comment: "Oracle Database Client" or "Oracle Instant Client" ? We found these two programs. Which one shall we install? And what "here" means? Home PC or Azure terminal?

Comment: I've no idea - I vaguely recall using Oracle Instant Client on a Windows machine before, but I am out of the loop. I'd be surprised if Oracle Server does not come bundled with something that allows a basic SQL interface out of the box though.

Comment: Client cannot be installed - found information. So what can we do if the only access we have is Azure web-based control panel and even ssh connection does not work to connect to VM.

Comment: What do you mean by "Client cannot be installed"?

Comment: On the internet it says that the Oracle client cannot be currently installed in Azure terminal. And as for the ports, they are open but only allow his IP. So by "blocking" he meant limiting the access to only his IP.

Comment: Oh dear. Well, it is hard to advise further, given there is nothing new in front of me to look at. I don't think you've elucidated on why you're helping despite not being an employee, and why the employee has been left to flounder for a full 14 days, and why the employer is not wanting to assist despite there being no scope for productivity. I wonder if the employee needs to push harder on getting colleague assistance?

Comment: Would it be acceptable for the employee to install Oracle Server locally, and carry out the actual work on a local instance, rather than using a remote/internet instance?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming or software development. Instead, this question should be asked on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) (I _think_, but please check yourself what's on-topic there) or otherwise SuperUser.

Comment: PS: and then there's also [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) _for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment_.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain here where to look. The error you are getting is mainly due to two reasons: 1) your tnsnames.ora file is incorrect or 2) the service on the database side are not registered with the listener.
Please check both, make sure that the service listed in listener.ora file is registered on the database side with listener.

Also make sure that ORACLE_HOME and/or TNS_ADMIN variables are defined on the client side. To see if the port is open between client and db server  you can do the following:

```
telnet <db-server-IP> <port_nr>
```

Also check out this oracle documentation detailing steps on how to install and configure Oracle Azure:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/vm/installation-of-an-oracle-database-on-azure